# Action parameter of form wrong when changing it via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, action

I am encountering this strange behaviour with jquery and I can't seem to fix it.
Basically what is happening is I am trying to set the action parameter of a form to a specific URL before submitting it. 
When I submit the form, for some reason the URL I set it to just gets appended to a different URL, which I guess is the URL that was in there before.

This is the code I am using to set the action parameter.

```
    //clear action parameter
    jQuery("form[name='form1']").attr('action',''); 
    alert(forwardUrl);

    //set the action parameter
    jQuery("form[name='form1']").attr('action',forwardUrl);
    //action parameter output
    alert('action parameter attribute: ' +  jQuery("form[name='form1']").attr('action'));

    //submit form
    jQuery("form[name='form1']").submit();
```

So for example for using the `forwardUrl = "test.php"`
the output of both alerts is `test.php`.

However when I run the code and the form is submitting it is POSTING the values to `https://www.test.com/test.php`.

I realize that it could be the standard behaviour to append to the url it is posted from. If that is the case how can I POST to a different URL that happens to be `forwardUrl`?

I also tried to use .prop() instead of .attr().

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you only provide a relative path, then the value will be appended to the current URL. If you want to specify a different domain, you need to provide an absolute path, eg. `https://www.foo.com/test.php`

Comment: you have to include full url instead of the filename if you don't want to redirect to the relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute path, as mentioned by Rory:

```
baseUrl = "https://www.test2.com/";  // Domain you need to send the form to

forwardUrl = baseUrl + "test.php";
```

Comment: The problem was that the URL was URI encoded, so it did not recognize it as the full URL, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the `action` when you click on the `submit` button with the help of `onclick` attribute

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit' onclick='this.form.action="forwardUrl";' />
```

or change your code to something like this, first provide a `id` to the form and use that `id` to set the `action` attribute

```
document.getElementById('formID').action = 'forwardUrl';
```

or by using form name as

```
document.getElementsByName("form1")[0].action = 'forwardUrl';
```

Comment: This does sound like a viable solution, unfortunately for me it didn't do the trick. I managed to fix it by using 'decodeURIComponent(forwardUrl);' though, as mentioned in my answer. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by using `decodeURIComponent(forwardUrl)` on the forwardUrl.